# when I am using accesskey and secret key the Amazon S3 signed URL validation is working fine which is 7 days but with IAM role it is expiring soon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-s3-client, aws-iam-authenticator

Amazon S3 signed URL, when I am using accesskey and secret key the signed URL validation is working fine which is 7 days but with IAM role it is getting expired soon (within 1 day).

I am expecting the similar result with both accesskey and IAM role

Comment: What do you mean by "with IAM role"? Are you saying that the Pre-signed URL was generated by an IAM Role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Amazon S3 pre-signed URL is just like a normal URL pointing to an object in Amazon S3, except that it has additional information appended:

- An **Access Key** to identify the credentials that are authorizing the access
- An **expiry period** after which the pre-signed URL will not work
- A **Signature** that validates the above information

The pre-signed URL will use the permissions of the credentials that were used to 'sign' the URL. Thus, if a user who does *not* have access to an object creates a pre-signed URL, then that pre-signed URL will not grant access.

Similarly, if the pre-signed URL is created by temporary credentials associated with an IAM Role, then the pre-signed URL will not work beyond the validity period of the IAM Role credentials. This is because those underlying credentials are no longer valid, so any pre-signed URLs created by those credentials will not be valid. The pre-signed URL is effectively saying "I am these credentials and I permit access", but if the credentials don't have access then the object can't have access.

Therefore, your options are:

- When Assuming the IAM Role, **request a longer validity period**. You can specify a `DurationSeconds` of up to 12 hours. This is, however, less than the 7 days you wanted.
- When generating the pre-signed URL, **use permanent credentials** that are therefore valid for the desired pre-signed URL expiry period.

Comment: What if the accesskey I'm using to generate signed urls has a policy attached to it preventing it from being used by certain IP addresses, does this policy apply to the signed urls as well?

Comment: Yes. When a pre-signed URL is being used, it is actually using the permissions of the credentials / Access Key that generated the pre-signed URL, as if those credentials were actually being used (because they are!). The "pre-signed" bit is simply a way of approving that specific call.